# What stats should I look out for when buying a fast USB drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-3, usb-2

What facts and figures should I look for speediest copying of single large ISO or multimedia files (700Mb to 4.5Gb)?

Also, if a flash drive is the fastest USB-3 compatible device, can I assume it will be the fastest at USB-2 also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for USB 3.0 and High Write Speeds, everything else is almost pointless :P

a USB 3.0 drive with read 100/10 write is worse than one that is read 70/40 write 
it also depends on how much you gonna write/use it :)

Answer (score 1):

[Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomehardware.com) did a review on [USB 3.0 Thumb Drives](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/usb-3.0-thumb-drive-review,3477.html) about 6 months ago, and that would be a great article to read to find some of the fastest performing drives.

If you get a USB 3 drive, make sure you have a USB 3 slot on your computer (It looks like a normal USB slot except its blue). If you plug a USB 3 into a USB 2 slot, it will run at USB 2 speeds. It may get closer to the theoretical speeds of the USB 2, but it will still run slower than if it was in a USB 3 slot.